# Scanning huge audio files is slow, but does it have to be?

Tags: performance, music-player, media-scanner

I am using Musicolet player which has an option to use Musicolet scanner or system scanner for media scanning. I wonder why scanning some single huge file is so slow? Does the scanner have to scan each file byte by byte or what takes so long?